# Two nouns sharing an adjective, can the definite article of the second noun be omitted?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, definite-article

In the following sentence, the nouns “consumption” and “use” share the adjective “high”.

I would like to know if it is grammatically correct to omit the definite article "the" of the second noun “use”:

> The consumption of soft drinks and **the** use of sedentary transportation
>   is high in the south region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically the articles are optional in this case, but, for ease of comprehension, I'd use both or omit both. People start trying to find subtle changes in meaning when structure changes for no apparent reason.

Of course the use of "is" as the verb is incorrect. The subject of this sentence is plural.

> A and B are high